# Arc-length of curve $y$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Check if the following curve is regular.

$$y(t)=( \cos^2 t, \sin^2 t) \text{ with } 0<t < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Find a unit speed reparametrization of the regular curve.

I have shown that the curve is regular.

To find a unit speed reparametrization, I calculated the arc-length of $y$ with starting point the point $(0,1)$:

$$s(t)= \int_0^t ||y'(u)|| du= \int_0^t \sqrt{ (- \sin(2u))^2+ (\sin(2u))^2}= \sqrt{2}\int_0^t \sin(2u) du= \sqrt{2} \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos (2t)}{2}\right)$$

Is it right so far?

Because I found the solution of the exercise at the book and there $s(t)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \cos^2t-1 \right)$.

Comment: $\cos(2t)=\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)=2\cos^2(t)-1$

Comment: So should the result be $s(t)=\sqrt{2} \sin^2 t$? @Reveillark

Comment: What I meant was that if you substitute the identity I wrote above into your result you'll see that it coincides with the solution you found in the book (some algebraic manipulation is needed).

Comment: @Reveillark $$\sqrt{2} \left( \frac{1}{2}- \frac{\cos {2t}}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\cos^2 t-1) \Rightarrow \cos^2 t=1$$

So the results shouldn't be the same.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Doesn't it hold that $$\int \sin{2u}=-\frac{\cos{2u}}{2}+c$$ ?

Comment: I got $s(t)=\sqrt{2}\sin^2{t}$ ...

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I missed a minus sign in my head. How did you derive the formula for $\| y'(u) \|$ in the integral?
@ililil That and the OPs result are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I correct my statement, that if you multiply your result by $0.5$, the 2 functions are equal. I am not sure where that (0.5) is from.

Comment: $y'(u)=(-2\sin(u)\cos(u),2\sin(u)\cos(u))=(-\sin(2u),\sin(2u))$

$||y'(u)||=\sqrt{(-\sin(2u))^2+(\sin(2u))^2}=\sqrt{2}\sin(2u)$

@Reveillark